# How many different sets can be created from $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ so that none of these sets are allowed to contain both $x$ and $x+2$?

Tags: combinatorics

I've tried numerous ways to solve the task, but none of them worked at all.
My first attempt was to try to calculate the amount of complementary events 
(so the sets which contain either $\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{3, 5\}$, ... or $\{8, 10\}$). 
After a while of struggling, I realized I didn't really get closer to find the solution.

However, I wrote a program that counts all the possibilities, and it gave $168$ as a result - which seems about correct to me.

I’d be really grateful if any of you could help me solving this problem.

Comment: $169$ would sound more likely to me. Did you forget to count the empty set?

Comment: You can finish your first attempt by a (not too nice)  alternating sum formula.

Comment: Yes, it's 169 if you include the empty set.

Comment: [This is a duplicate post of the question you posted yesterday, then deleted after receiving two downvotes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789212/how-many-different-sets-can-be-created-from-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-so-t).  Do not delete posts, and then repost them, to circumvent downvotes, closure, or for any other reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker already posted the question, then deleted the question when it received two downvotes.  A couple hours later, they posted it again, which you see here.

Comment: You really should have edited the first version of the question into shape. That's the site norm. You see, the first question is not really deleted. Users with more than 10k rep can still see it, so now there is a sad orphaned question. Also, having asked a deleted question may come back to bite you. The system keeps track of such things, and if there are too many poorly received questions, then you will bluntly be barred from asking new questions. So, EDITING a poorly received question is always the go-to reaction.

Comment: But, you did a fine job adding the explanations of your efforts and your findings to this version. If only you had done all that to the first version I would have upvoted it. Now it feels like I would be rewarding "bad behavior". Anyway, newbies often err the same way. This is just something you should be aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can handle the odd and even numbers independently of each other, and then just multiply the number of allowed sets of odd numbers with how many allowed sets of even numbers.

Within each of these, there are only $5$ numbers to consider. In this small case it's probably easiest to just enumerate the options by hand: $1$ empty set, $5$ sets with one element, $6$ sets with two elements, $1$ set with three elements. In total $13$.

If you need to deal with a larger base set, you can also write down a recurrence. It turns out that the number of subsets of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ that don't contain any neighboring numbers is exactly the $(n+1)$th *Fibonacci number*, and $F_6=13$.

Comment: Thank you! :-) I don't know how I haven't thought of this.

Comment: You answered the duplicate post of a user who deleted their first, downvoted post.  Please see my comment below the question.